# How can I configure what to cache in nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, cache

I have a REST API for which I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy.  I want to cache certain calls to the API which use absolute time references in the request but I want to not cache calls which use relative time references.

For example, I don't want to cache responses to the following request:

```
GET - http://mydomain:8080/sel/cpu?endingHoursAgo=0&hoursToShow=2
```

But I do want to cache responses to the following request:

```
GET - http://mydomain:8080/sel/cpu?from=2014-07-04T08:30:00.000%2B01:00&to=2014-07-04T10:30:00.000%2B01:00
```

How can I form a `proxy_cache_key` in nginx that will cache the latter but not the former?

Comment: Looking on how you want to do the caching, I rather think you should put the "what to cache" logic inside the application, if possible, and let nginx do the caching based on cache headers.

Comment: The application should be sending the appropriate Cache-Control headers.